# not able to create bat file having two lines using cmd

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I want to create a bat file that contains

```
hello
world
```

using cmd. tried to use

```
echo hello\nworld :> test.bat
```

but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you need..

```
C:\>echo hello > test.bat & echo world >> test.bat

C:\>type test.bat
hello
world
```

Now if you wanted to echo back hello world, you will really want:

```
C:\>echo echo hello > test.bat & echo echo world >> test.bat

C:\>type test.bat
echo hello
echo world
```

**NOTE:** The use of > and >>..  One > will over-write your file..  Two >> will append or add to it..  The echo. will put a new line or a space which is why I removed it.

One more thing, if you want to Call or use this in another batch file, you need to do one additional change and that is to double up the "&&":

```
echo echo hello > test.bat && echo echo world >> test.bat

C:\>type test.bat
echo hello
echo world
```

Hope this helps!